# Will this xml code shows admob on the bottom of the app?

Tags: xml, admob

I am developing an app for android with eclipse, and I have been wondering will this xml code shows admob on the bottom of the page.

I launched this on emulator, and admob didnt show, but I dont know is ito because of code or because I must wait about 2 min to see admob.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rltvLayout1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />



        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="my code"
            ads:refreshInterval="60" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are missing

```
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

try this if it is not help then put your **java** file.